# Prove that if $[a] + [b] \equiv [a] + [c] \pmod n$, then $[b] \equiv [c] \pmod n$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The question is very clear that we are dealing with classes. Does that change anything in this case? This was an unsolved example for class and I feel it's unusual that I don't know how to begin.

Answer (score 1):

How is the notation $[a]\equiv[b]\pmod n$ defined? Normally one would write either $a\equiv b\pmod n$ or $[a]=[b]$. Unless a definition of $[a]\equiv[b]\pmod n$ has been given, I’d regard the notation in the title as at an error on the part of the person who wrote up the question.

Comment: Thank you, there was no definition, just my confusion.

Comment: @grayQuant: That’s what I was afraid of. In that case I’d treat it as if it were written without the square brackets. If it’s something that’s to be handed in, I’d explain why I was doing so.

Comment: Ethan I do write in Tex, there was no need.

Comment: @grayQuant My bad,  sorry.

Comment: I should have done a better job explaining, my confusion is why [] were used, I assumed classes. The problem was presented to me in that way without further explanation. @BrianM.Scott – grayQuant just now edit

Comment: @grayQuant: Yes, I understood that. My reaction is as I said: whoever wrote up the question either was confused or had a mental hiccup.

Comment: And I’d really like to know what the downvoter was thinking; I’d be happy to improve the answer if it’s not clear enough.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know too, why the downvote?

Comment: Why was an answer deleted? The poster made a good assumption... that the notation could be ignored.

Comment: @grayQuant: Probably because it was pointed out that that answer didn’t address the question that you actually asked; it simply took for granted that the notation was a mistake and worked the problem on that assumption.